# Group by condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to cut the continues data into some group. 
I have some data like this:

```
Index Age Predict
0     23    0
1     39    0
2     70    0
3     41    1
4     50    0
5     17    0
6     29    1
```

I try:

```
df_1 = df[['Age','Predict']]
data = df_1.sort_values(by='Age')
```

After sorting:

```
Index Age Predict
5     17    0
0     23    0
6     29    1
1     39    0
3     41    1
2     70    0
4     50    0
```

What can i do to classifier data into the group:

```
Index Age Predict

group 1:
5     17    0
0     23    0

group 2:
6     29    1

group 3:
1     39    0

group 4:
3     41    1

group 5:
2     70    0
4     50    0
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: you need `pd.cut` then use a dict comprehension, if you specify your age ranges that would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, the groups you want are created from Predict, where `diff` between following rows are not equal to 0. so you could create a column:

```
data_ = df.sort_values('Age')
data_['gr'] = data_['Predict'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
print (data_)
   Index  Age  Predict  gr
5      5   17        0   1
0      0   23        0   1
6      6   29        1   2
1      1   39        0   3
3      3   41        1   4
4      4   50        0   5
2      2   70        0   5
```

Or if you want to split your data and not create the group column, one way is to create a dictionary that contains each group

```
data_ = df.sort_values('Age')
d = {i: dfg 
     for i,(_, dfg) in enumerate(data_.groupby(data_['Predict'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()),1)}
print (d[1])
   Index  Age  Predict
5      5   17        0
0      0   23        0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby((df['Predict'] != df['Predict'].shift(1)).cumsum())
```

Basically check if the current value is not the same previous value, if not increment. This will allow you to group by the change in values of Predict

Answer (score 1):

Using `.grouby` and `.cumsum()`

```
for i, grp in data.groupby([(data['Predict'] != data['Predict'].shift()).cumsum()]):
    print('group', i)
    print(grp)
```

Result:

```
group 1
   Age  Predict
5   17        0
0   23        0
group 2
   Age  Predict
6   29        1
group 3
   Age  Predict
1   39        0
group 4
   Age  Predict
3   41        1
group 5
   Age  Predict
4   50        0
2   70        0
```